# How can I get the @Html.TextBox to center vertically in the cell?

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I have a table defined in cshtml with the following row:

```
<table class="tableinfo">
    <tr>
        <td class="one"></td>
        <td>User Name</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBox("username", User.Identity.Name)</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

The `TextBox` is not centering vertically with the following from `Style.css`:

```
table.tableinfo {
   padding-left: 0;
}

   table.tableinfo tr {
      margin: 25px 0;
      padding-left: 45px;
      vertical-align: middle;
   }

      table.tableinfo tr td.one {
         width: 3px;
         background: url("../Images/orderedList1.png") no-repeat;
      }
        table.tableinfo tr td.one + td + td {
           margin: 0;
           vertical-align: middle;
        }
```

The result is:
[image]

You can see "User Name" is centered vertically with the '1' icon but the TextBox is hugging the bottom of the row. How can I get the TextBox to center vertically in the cell?

Comment: this isn't really a razor question, just css

Comment: The only reason I put razor is because of the `@Html.TextBox`. All other solutions point to `<input type=text .../>`.

Comment: `@Html.TextBox` becomes `<input type='text'`.  Check the html on the rendered page.  Razor is just helping you out

Comment: What CSS have you defined for `tableinfo` and `one`?

Comment: @rageit: added `CSS` for `tableinfo` and one (as well as `tr`).